# O que significa a sintaxe "14px/1" em declaração de tamanhos de fontes?

Tags: css3

Volta e meia quando dou uma olhada em algum código-fonte de um site, encontro um código que ainda não entendi o seu significado quando a declaração do atributo `font`.

Exemplo:

```
p {
  font: Arial 14px/1;
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber exatamente pra que serve esse `14px/1`. Qual é o sentido dele?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isto é uma especie de atalho para aplicar o `line-height`, que é muitas vezes importante para a fonte escolhida dependendo do tipo de fonte, então fazer isto:

```css
.test {
     font: 14px/1 Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Olá mundo, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar</div>
```

Seria o mesmo que:

```css
.test {
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Olá mundo, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar</div>
```

Só pra constar, a ordem do `font: Arial 14px/1;` esta errada e provavelmente não vai funcionar, o correto é `font: 14px/1 Arial;` pois o `font:` conforme o [**link da W3**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand) ele trabalha nesta ordem:

> [ [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ]? <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]? <'font-family'> ] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar | inherit

---

### Valores em line-height

Outro detalhe é que `line-height: 1` ou `/1` **não são** a mesma coisa que `line-height: 1px` e `/1px`.

O `line-height` tendo o valor `1` irá assumir o tamanho de `font-size` que nos exemplos é `14px`, se fosse `line-height: 2` iria assumir `28px`, que é o dobro da fonte e assim por diante.

Veja a diferença:

```css
.comPX {
    font: 14px/1px Arial;
}

.comPT {
    font: 14px/1pt Arial;
}

.sem {
    font: 14px/1 Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="comPX">
Olá mundo, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo
</div>

<hr>

<div class="comPT">
Olá mundo, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo
</div>

<hr>

<div class="sem">
Olá mundo, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo, bar, foo
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, +1. Muito boa a resposta, eu nem imaginava que fosse isso!

Answer (score 0):

Isso é uma forma abreviada para o mesmo código a seguir da propriedade font:

```
font-family: Arial
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1;
```

Este é o syntax da propriedade font de acordo com o [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp):

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family|caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit;
```

Comment: `/1` não é equivalente a `1px`, é equivalente a `14px`, ambos não são equivalentes.

Comment: Obigado pelo aviso @GuilhermeNascimento